# How do I stop the execution of watchdog after file has been found?

Tags: python, watchdog

I have the following code written to search for all csv files in a file path and print the first csv file. However, my code keeps running even after the watchdog has executed the action. How do I get the watchdog to stop once it finds and prints the set file.

Essentially, I want the code to quit running if the file is found and read.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer 
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    path = "C:/Users/Desktop/Test/"
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

 # convert 1st csv in list to pandas df then print
    first_csv = pd.read_csv(all_filenames[0])
    print(first_csv)
    
   
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)  

    observer.start()  

#for starting the observer thread
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

Comment: Give it a different event handler that tells it to stop.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: Take a look at the `watchdog.events` module -- things like `LoggingEventHandler` aren't magic, they're just classes like any other, and you can make your own class there that _in addition to_ logging also calls `observer.stop()`.

Comment: The other thing you might consider doing is evaluating whether a lighter-weight library than `watchdog` is better suited to your use case. There are a _lot_ of filesystem event monitoring libraries in Python; watchdog isn't the only game in town, and if it's forcing you to write a lot of boilerplate, maybe it's worth picking a different one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler


class EventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=['*.csv'], ignore_directories=True, case_sensitive=True)
    def on_created(self, event):
        global Created
        Created = True
        print(f'{event.src_path} has been created!')

def FileWatcher(Path):
    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=Path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while not Created:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Created = False
    FileWatcher('./watched_directory')
```